# Filtering mobile browsers by failure to execute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just getting some css together for a mobile web app (using the xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11 dtd) and was trying to think of a reliable way to filter for mobile browsers. I've taken a look at http://detectmobilebrowser.com but that appears to filter on the basis of a list of string matches.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1 - In the css, set the parts of the page to hide from mobile browsers to not display

```
#hideMeFromMobiles{display:none;}
```

2 - Call a script using a reliable library that is pretty much certain to fail in mobile browsers. The script does something like this (pseudocode)

```
if browser.window.width >= 480px then {
    $(#hideMeFromMobiles).addStyle(display:block;)
    }
```

The idea is for the script to fail non-destructively on mobile browsers and run succesfully in desktop web browsers.

My question is this:

Firstly will this work? Is there some reason this is a dead-end and I should move to another solution?

And secondly, could someone confirm the correct jQuery syntax?

Thanks for your help,
Dug

Answer (score 4):

First of all, mobile browsers can lie about width and scale or scroll.

Second, jQuery is a pretty fat library for many mobile devices. It doesn't run on all of them, and it flushes the cache of some of them. [xui](http://github.com/brianleroux/xui) may be a better choice. The jQuery team is looking into making a more modular version of the library for mobile devices.

Third, you're going to need some quotes around that "#hideMeFromMobiles" specifier.

Fourth, some mobile browsers by default have JavaScript off (I'm looking at you Blackberry browsers). You'll need some `<noscript>` markup.

[ppk](http://www.quirksmode.org/) has been testing the pitfalls of mobile browers. You should start at his [mobile tests](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/).

Finally, some mobile browsers are great, especially the new ones on smart phones that use WebKit. I'd test the site on iPhone, Android, Storm, and Pre before forcing a mobile page onto them.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to specify a specific stylesheet just for mobiles by linking in a special css that will only be loaded by handheld devices, normal browser will ignore this :

```
<link href="/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

In the normal CSS have

```
#hideMeFromMobiles{}
```

And in the mobile css have

```
#hideMeFromMobiles{display:none;}
```

If you link the mobile css after the normal css, the mobile css settings will override the normal ones.

Comment: Thanks @Fungus, I've been warned against using the media attribute. Apparently it isn't that reliable and the failures aren't consistent. I'm trying to think of a crude-but-reliable solution...

Comment: Hmmm.. Ive never heard of it being any more unreliable than any other web technology. But there you go! Will have to look that up. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.iui-js.org/ which I think looks more cleaner to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While providing options can be helpful, you should at least try to answer the original question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer for info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about mobile development, you should consider building separate pages for mobile.

Although `#hideMeFromMobiles{display:none;}` will work, all the content and images will still be downloaded by those on a mobile, not to mention the other CSS and scripts running on the page.  That will increase significantly the visitor's bandwidth.  Better to serve them specific mobile pages.

As for detection, I think http://detectmobilebrowser.com is one of the best methods.  No need to reinvent the wheel.  As mentioned in other answers, screen width can fool you.